# ¿Como subir imagenes a mi storage/app/public?

Tags: laravel, storage

Tengo una duda,estoy subiendo imagenes de perfil creando una carpeta llamada **"photo-users"** ,se sube correctamente ,pero quisiera que se me subiera al **storage/app/public/{photo-users}** pero no se sube de esta forma si no que se sube : **storage/app/{photo-users}** , quisiera saber porque sucede esto y como poder solucionarlo,estoy apuntando a esa ruta ,a si que no se que estoy haciendo mal ,de antemano gracias! dejo el codigo:

Controlador:

```php
  $url = Storage::put("photo-users",$request->file("image_path"));
```

Filesystem

```php
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public'),
```

```php
  'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
```

Imagen referencia :

[image: img]

Comment: Que valor tiene [FILESYSTEM_DISK](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/39f4830e92a7467b2a7fe6bc23d0ec14bc3b46a6/.env.example#L20) en el archivo `.env`? Limpiaste la cache después de hacer los cambios?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Hola!! ,Al parecer lo tengo en "local",será ese el problema?ya que, en archivo filesystems.php lo tengo por default como publico

Comment: Corrí estos dos comandos : php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear pero tampoco se actualizo el archivo .env,dando referencia al disk default public que indique

Comment: `'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public')` quiere decir que el disco por default es el que está en la clave `FILESYSTEM_DISK` del archivo `.env`, y de no existir ese valor en el .env, se usará `'public'` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-env

Comment: Bastaria que en el filestystem_disk indique que me tome el public?, ya que, tengo dos disk uno publico y otro local, en ese caso, al indicar public como default me esta tomando igualmente el local?,como indica **FILESYSTEM_DISK**

Comment: Como está puesto en la pregunta, el que vale es el del `.env`., así que tendrías que definirlo ahí. Si no, puedes escribir directamente `'default' => 'public'` en el archivo de configuración